# tootips in Shipping Address on checkout page frontend magento 1.9

Tags: magento

How to add tootips in Shipping Address on checkout page frontend  magento 1.9 
EX: Tooltip for indicating this filed is for the person who is receiving flower

Comment: you can add tooltip in template file checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we can show the tooltip on checkout page using css

Example :

```
Step-1 : open file app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\checkout\onepage\shipping.phtml and paste css
<style>
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

Step-2 : find

```
<label for="shipping:company"><?php echo $this->__('Company') ?></label>
```

and replace with

```
<label class="tooltip" for="shipping:company"><span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span><?php echo $this->__('Company') ?></label>
```